# Confidence interval length less than 2

Tags: normal-distribution, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

The time of execution for one program follows a normal distribution. For a sample of size $40$ we have: $\overline{x} = 32.2 s$ and $\sigma^{2} = 3.1s^{2}$

How many times we have to execute the program to obtain a $95\%$ confidence interval with the lenght of interval less than 2 seconds?

Because the program follows a normal distribution we have that de confidence interval is

$$\left[ \frac{1}{n}\sum X_{i} - \frac{Z_{\alpha/2}\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},\frac{1}{n}\sum X_{i} + \frac{Z_{\alpha/2}\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \right]$$

so, the lenght interval is
$$2\frac{Z_{\alpha/2}\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

and we need that
$$\frac{Z_{\alpha/2}\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} < 1$$
I first thought that I could use $\sigma = \sqrt{3.1}$ but this was for the sample of size $40$ so i don't know if I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation you know the distribution is Gaussian but you eve do not know its variance. Given a sample size =40 you can assume that your $\hat{\sigma^2}=3.1$ is a good approximation...thus your reasonig is good and you can find

$$n\ge 1.96^2\cdot3.1\approx 11.91=12$$